# Custom function error - "Not Defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Javascript code:

```
$('td:eq(2)', nRow).html('<a class="critical" href="#" OnClick="toAjax(\''+aData[1]+'\', \''+aData[2]+'\');">'+aData[3]+'</a>');
```

I'm getting in Firebug the following error message

> toAjax is not defined

My function:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        oTable = $('.statisticsTable').dataTable({

                "bJQueryUI" : true,

                "iDisplayLength" :50,

                "sAjaxSource": 'arrays.txt',

                "aoColumns"   : [{ "bSearchable": true, "bVisible": false },null, null, null, null, null,null,null,null,null,null],

                "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {

                    if (aData[3] == "1") {
                        $('td:eq(2)', nRow).html('<a class="critical" href="#" OnClick="toAjax(\''+aData[1]+'\', \''+aData[2]+'\');">'+aData[3]+'</a>');

                        } 

                    else if

                    (aData[4] == 123) {
                        $('td:eq(3)', nRow).html( '<a class="critical" href="serverID='+aData[0]+'&db='+aData[1]+'&task=Workload'+'">'+aData[2]+'<span class="highcharts"></span></a>' ).attr("class","kritikal");



                    } 

                    else if

                    (aData[3] >1) {
                        $('td:eq(3)', nRow).html( '<a id="ajax_call" class="critical" href="#">'+aData[3]+'<span class="highcharts"></span></a>' );

                        } 

                    return nRow;
                },


            } );


        function toAjax( server, db )
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "someurl.php",
                data: "server=" + server + "&db=" + db,
                success: function(msg){
                    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                }
            });
        }


    });
```

Comment: Where are the "id" and "name" variables defined in the toAjax function?

Comment: Make sure your `function toAjax( ... )` is declared _before_ you use it in your `OnClick=""` attribute.

Comment: Could you show some more code?

Comment: Where do you declare this function? If it is inside the `document.ready` handler, it will be local to that function only. But why do you create the HTML like this anyway? If you use jQuery, then use it properly and attach the event handler with jQuery.

Comment: You could really help yourself syntax-wise by just adding the handler with the jQuery `.bind()` or `.click()` handler after adding the element, instead of inline when you add the element.

Comment: @JamWaffles: Function declarations can be put after their use: http://jsfiddle.net/23ysB/.

Comment: @primvdb Of course! As soon as I read your comment I remembered that JS pushes all definitions to the top of the script.

Comment: This example seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Va39r/ Make sure you're not declaring the `toAjax()` function within the `$(document).ready()` scope, but in the global scope.

Comment: Really study and understand what Jared is trying to tell you about the `.click()` handler.  After all, thanks to jQuery... there is no longer a convenience to using that inline JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, now that you've added your code, you DO have the `toAjax()` declared in a function scope. Take it out of the `$(document).ready()` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get this to work (a simplified example):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var aData = [1,2,3,4];
    $('td:eq(2)')
        .html('<a class="critical" href="#">'+aData[3]+'</a>')
        .children('a.critical')
            .click(function(){
                toAjax(aData[1],aData[2]);
            });
});

function toAjax( server, db )
{
    console.log(server, db);
    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Va39r/2/

Note how I add the `click` handler AFTER I add the html. This makes adding the handler much cleaner than with an inline text.

**EDIT** - After seeing your edit, the below is the reason your `toAjax()` function is 'not defined'.

Also, I would check to make sure the `toAjax()` is declared and not within a function scope (for instance, you don't have it in a `$(document).ready()` block).